# Angular JS controller is not working in IOS 14

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-controller, ios14

Angular JS controller is not working in IOS 14. But its working below IOS 14.

App shows white or blank screen. I don't have any issue with splash screen.

Controllers and templates are working fine in Android version and in browser.

I am developing IOS app using Cordova and Angular JS.

Below are the code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/developer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nprogress.css"> <!-- Infinite Scroll -->
</head>
<body ng-app="raffle">
    <div id="noNetId"></div>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Spinner JS -->
    <script src="js/spin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-spinner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Spinner JS -->
    
    <!-- Infinite Scroll -->
    <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <script src="js/infinite-scroll.js"></script>
    <!-- Infinite Scroll -->

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('raffle', ['raffle.services', 'ngRoute', 'angularSpinner', "infinite-scroll"]).run(function(DB) {
    DB.init();
});
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: "views/login.html",
            controller: "loginCtrl"
        })
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/list.html",
            controller: "listCtrl"
        })
});
angular.module('raffle.config', [])
    .constant('DB_CONFIG', {
        name: 'testdatabase',
        tables: []
    });
angular.module('raffle.services', ['raffle.config'])
    // DB wrapper
    .factory('DB', function($q, DB_CONFIG) {
        var self = this;
        self.db = null;

        self.init = function() {
            // Use self.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: DB_CONFIG.name}); in production
            //self.db = window.openDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name, '1.0', 'database', -1);
            self.db = window.openDatabase(DB_CONFIG.name, '1.0', DB_CONFIG.name, 10000000);

            angular.forEach(DB_CONFIG.tables, function(table) {
                var columns = [];

                angular.forEach(table.columns, function(column) {
                    columns.push(column.name + ' ' + column.type);
                });
                //self.query('drop table ' + table.name);
                var query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table.name + ' (' + columns.join(',') + ')';
                self.query(query);
                console.log('Table ' + table.name + ' initialized');

            });
        };

        self.query = function(query, bindings) {
            bindings = typeof bindings !== 'undefined' ? bindings : [];
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            self.db.transaction(function(transaction) { //alert(query);
                transaction.executeSql(query, bindings, function(transaction, result) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }, function(transaction, error) { //alert(error);
                    deferred.reject(error);
                    console.log(error);
                });
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        self.fetchAll = function(result) {
            var output = [];
            var len = result.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    output.push(result.rows.item(i));
                }
            }
            return output;
        };

        self.fetch = function(result) {
            var len = result.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                return result.rows.item(0);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };

        return self;
});

alert("Test"); //working
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, DB, $http, $rootScope, $route, usSpinnerService) {
    alert("Main controller"); //not working
});
app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, DB, $http, $rootScope, $route, usSpinnerService, $routeParams) {
    alert("List controller"); //not working
});
```

list.html

```
<h1>List</h1>
<p>Some content goes here...</p>
```

Please help me. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u got solution on this ?

Comment: Angular JS version 1 is not working or supporting in IOS. So we developed in Angular 9 its working now and we uploaded to App Store. All good now.